# Visual Studio Extension for sorting field assignments

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, add-on

When various objects have many fields in them it is sometimes a daunting task to ensure that you've assigned all fields properly especially when having to maintain someone else's code or simply going through a project cleanup. Is there a tool or extension for visual studio that can be used to sort fields assignments alphabetically by the object's field names as following:

From

```
ObjectName obj = new ObjectName
{
    SecondField = anotherObject.SecondField,
    ThirdField  = anotherObject.ThirdField,
    FirstField  = anotherObject.FirstField
};
```

to

```
ObjectName obj = new ObjectName
{
    FirstField  = anotherObject.FirstField,
    SecondField = anotherObject.SecondField,
    ThirdField  = anotherObject.ThirdField
};
```

I usually avoid this issue by using a simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> when assigning each field which brings up an alphabetic list of fields to assign then I assign everything in a sorted manner.

Comment: If you're struggling to work out whether all fields are assigned (and I'm not sure *sorting* fields provides that much help over e.g. *counting* the number of assignments and knowing how many assignments should happen), it may suggest you have too many [God objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object)

Comment: Remember to be careful sorting fields of structs also. I use Resharper, and luckily it is smart enough to not apply its re-order formatting to structs by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a tool or extension for visual studio that can be used to sort fields assignments alphabetically by the object's field names

You can try to use the Visual Studio extension [CodeMaid](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveCadwallader.CodeMaid) to sort object's field names:

[image]

[image]

For more details, please visit: http://www.codemaid.net

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.